# Programa de simulación de tirada de dados

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que simule una cierta cantidad tiradas de dados dada por el usuario con una cantidad de caras por dado también dada por el usuario y con una cantidad de dados también definida por el usuario.
Tengo dos problemas, primer no logro hacer que se tire la cantidad de dados dada por el usuario, y el otro problema es que cuando intento correr el código, funciona bien hasta que llega a la parte en la que debería decir los resultados, donde me sale el siguiente error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "dado.py", line 17, in
>
> result = rollDice(caras, cantidad, tiradas)
>
> File "dado.py", line 9, in rollDice
>
> rolls[resultado - 1] += 1
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import random

def rollDice(caras, cantidad, tiradas):
    rolls = [0] * caras
    for i in range(0, tiradas):
        roll_1 = int(random.randint(1,caras))
        roll_2 = int(random.randint(1,caras))
        resultado = roll_1 + roll_2
        rolls[resultado - 1] += 1
    return rolls

if __name__ == "__main__":
    caras = int(input("Inserte la cantidad de caras por dado: "))
    cantidad = int(input("\nInserte la cantidad de dados: "))
    tiradas = int(input("\nInserte la cantidad de tiradas: "))

    result = rollDice(caras, cantidad, tiradas)
    print(result[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Para "tirar" el número de dados ingresado tienes que usar otro `for` anidado, de forma que se llame tantas veces a `randint` como como dados hay en cada tirada.

El error se debe a la línea `rolls[resultado - 1]`, no se muy bien que pretendías con esto, pero resultado es un valor aleatorio generado mediante la suma de dos salidas de `randint`. Cada salida de `randint` puede llegar a ser como máximo el valor de `caras` (la longitud de `rolls`), si sumas dos salidas de `randint` puedes como máximo generar el índice `caras + caras`, índice que no existe en la lista. El índice debe ser la variable del primer `for` (la variable `i`) y debes sumar el resultado de cada dado:

```
import random


def roll_dice(caras, cantidad, tiradas):
    rolls = [0] * tiradas
    for i in range(tiradas):
        for _ in range(cantidad):
            t = random.randint(1, caras)
            rolls[i] += t           
    return rolls


if __name__ == "__main__":
    caras = int(input("Inserte la cantidad de caras por dado: "))
    cantidad = int(input("\nInserte la cantidad de dados: "))
    tiradas = int(input("\nInserte la cantidad de tiradas: "))

    result = rollDice(caras, cantidad, tiradas)
    print(result)
```

> ```
> Inserte la cantidad de caras por dado: 6
>
> Inserte la cantidad de dados: 3
>
> Inserte la cantidad de tiradas: 5
> [11, 9, 9, 7, 6]
> ```

Si te interesa conocer la salida dado por dado puedes usar una lista anidada:

```
def roll_dice(caras, cantidad, tiradas):
    rolls = [[0] * cantidad for _ in range(tiradas)]
    for i in range(tiradas):
        for j in range(cantidad):
            t = random.randint(1, caras)
            rolls[i][j] = t          
    return rolls
```

> ```
> Inserte la cantidad de caras por dado: 6
>
> Inserte la cantidad de dados: 3
>
> Inserte la cantidad de tiradas: 5
> [[1, 5, 2], [1, 3, 5], [6, 2, 4], [3, 2, 1], [4, 6, 6]]
> ```

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, por ejemplo, para Python >= 3.6 puedes usar `random.choices`:

```
def roll_dice(caras, cantidad, tiradas):
    rolls = [sum(random.choices(range(caras + 1), k=cantidad)) for _ in range(tiradas)]
    return rolls
```

Y para mostrar los resultados dado a dado:

```
def roll_dice(caras, cantidad, tiradas):
    rolls = [random.choices(range(caras + 1), k=cantidad) for _ in range(tiradas)]
    return rolls
```